# How to add namespace prefix at root XML using Python LXML?

Tags: python, lxml, xml-namespaces

I would like to have the following NS prefix **<qsp:** and **</qsp:**

```
<qsp:QSPart xmlns:qsp="urn:qvalent:quicksuper:gateway">
  <qsp:MemberRegistrationRequest/>
</qsp:QSPart>
```

How do I do that in LMXL python?

```
from lxml import etree

nsmap = {'qsp': 'urn:qvalent:quicksuper:gateway'}
nsprefix = nsmap['qsp']

QSPart = etree.Element('QSPart', nsmap=nsmap)
MemberRegistrationRequest = etree.SubElement(QSPart, etree.QName(nsprefix, 'MemberRegistrationRequest'))

print(etree.tostring(QSPart, pretty_print=True, encoding=str))
```

Result:

```
<QSPart xmlns:qsp="urn:qvalent:quicksuper:gateway">
  <qsp:MemberRegistrationRequest/>
</QSPart>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://lxml.de/2.1/namespace_extensions.html#id2), you need to fully qualify the element name in your call to `etree.Element`:

```
from lxml import etree

nsmap = {'qsp': 'urn:qvalent:quicksuper:gateway'}
nsprefix = nsmap['qsp']

QSPart = etree.Element(f'{{{nsmap["qsp"]}}}QSPart')
MemberRegistrationRequest = etree.SubElement(QSPart, etree.QName(nsprefix, 'MemberRegistrationRequest'))

print(etree.tostring(QSPart, pretty_print=True, encoding=str))
```

This outputs:

```
<ns0:QSPart xmlns:ns0="urn:qvalent:quicksuper:gateway">
  <ns0:MemberRegistrationRequest/>
</ns0:QSPart>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know your expected output, I wouldn't bother with all that (though I understand many people frown on this approach...) - just use from and to string:

```
frag_text = """<qsp:QSPart xmlns:qsp="urn:qvalent:quicksuper:gateway">
  <qsp:MemberRegistrationRequest/>
</qsp:QSPart>"""
fragment = etree.fromstring(frag_text)
print(etree.tostring(fragment).decode())
```

Output should be your expected output.